# Content not displaying inside div

Tags: html, css

This is my html code
I cannot understand why the contents are not showing inside the div.

```
      <div class="contact-form">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <form class="form-horizontal">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Full Name :</label>
                        <div class="">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" />
                        </div>
                    </div>              
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Subject :</label>
                        <div class="">
                            <textarea class="form-control"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>                                  
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
                    </div>                                                                                              
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Heres my style

```
.contact .contact-form{
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 5px;    
}
```

Can someone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question doesn't have enough detail which shows, what you want to achieve.

Comment: All i was asking is that the the child elements were not showing inside the parent div and it was showing outside the parent div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

**CSS**

```
.contact-form{
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;   
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/luispa/kd4kjdck/354/)**

Answer (score 0):

Because you have not used row div, you are using bootstrap structure ,so you should use cols (col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12) in row.

try this:

```
  <div class="row contact-form">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <form class="form-horizontal">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Full Name :</label>
                    <div class="">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                </div>              
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Subject :</label>
                    <div class="">
                        <textarea class="form-control"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>                                  
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
                </div>                                                                                              
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```